# Rails 3.2.13 vs Rails 4.0.1 - changed? method changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have recently noticed that the method `changed?` on ActiveRecord objects has changed between Rails 3.2.13 and Rails 4.0.1. The problem is with fields connected to integer fields in database. Let's assume I have model `Model` with `number` integer field:

```
# Rails 3.2.13

m = Model.last
m.number                #=> 5
m.number = '5hello'
m.number                #=> 5
m.number_changed?       #=> true
m.changed?              #=> true
m.changes               #=> {:number => [5,5]}

# Rails 4.0.1

m = Model.last
m.number                #=> 5
m.number = '5hello'
m.number                #=> 5
m.number_changed?       #=> false
m.changed?              #=> false
m.changes               #=> {}
```

This causes a number of extremely annoying issues with form validations - if a user is trying to change the integer value to have invalid characters (but the type cast will result in the same value as initial one), rails will not invoke `save` method and none of the validation (including `numericality: { only_integer: true }`) will be run.

I have managed to get around this problem by overriding `number_changed?` method to `super || number.to_s != number_before_type_cast`, however this is extremely ugly.

The question is: why was this changed? Is it a bug or is intentional change? How can it be fixed without overriding all meta methods for integer columns?

Comment: it is intentional change, `changed?` have different behavior between 3.2.13(tells you if your object has changed since its last save.) and 4.0.1(Returns true if any attribute have unsaved changes, false otherwise.).

Comment: @Monk_Code - Thanks, it would explain the behaviour changes, however it seems to be missed that it will cause validation issues. Hence I would categorize it as a bug in intentional change. :) Unless of course there was some mechanism added as well to handle those cases.

Comment: Excuse me but I don't understand how this affect validation. After form submitted the user has no way to alter the values. IMO because `m` is a persisted instance of a model, it should not be marked as changed if the change only happens in memory but not db level.

Comment: @BillyChan - If you edit an existing record and the only change you do is to change `5` into `5anything`, submission should fail on validations. However validations are not triggered, since rails assumes that the object has not changed and hence does not run any validations. On the other hand if you change it to `6something`, `changed?` returns true and validations are run.

Comment: @BroiSatse agreed. This looks like a bug. Validations should fail when number is set to "5anything" or "6something", right? Time to submit a patch to Rails.

Comment: It sounds like the comparison of changed is happening after typecasting. The typecasting is converting your integer + string back to an integer which matches it's previous value. AFAIK this is expected behavior.

Comment: @JasonWaldrip - This has been fixed in later versions (as you can see below it works correctly in 4.0.5). In 4.0.1 it breaks validations so it is hard to believe it is intentional.

Comment: If it's been fixed in a patch it would seem to indicate that it wasn't intentional and the solution would be to apply the patch. Otherwise I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure on how you're running your validations, but I have a model on my rails app which is called ExtraField and have the following validation:

```rb
class ExtraField < ActiveRecord::Base

  # stuff

  validates :display_order, numericality: { only_integer: true }

  # more stuff

end
```

I'm using rails 4.0.5 and I can do the following:

```
e = ExtraField.first
e.display_order           #=> 1
e.valid?                  #=> true
e.errors.messages         #=> {}
e.display_order = '1banana'
e.display_order           #=> 1
e.display_order_changed?  #=> false
e.changed?                #=> false
e.valid?                  #=> false
e.errors.messages         #=> {:display_order=>["is not a number"]}
```

So, although the record indeed isn't marked as changed ( what seems correct IMHO ), I can still run my validations and check that the model is not valid. Doesn't look like a bug to me, but just an intentional improvement.

If your form is only validating if the model is responding true to `changed?` maybe you should check your controller code. Or if you use a gem to help building the form it could be a bug in that gem I guess.

Comment: Yes, this issue has been fixed in later rails versions, however same validations run on 4.0.1 want add this error.